# Diagnostic & Usage On Apple Device

Tags: permission, repair, privacy, apple-diagnostics

Hoping someone can help:
I sent my apple device into a screen repair shop (had to drop off ipad and require to provide passcode)
Can I use the diagnostic and usage to see what apps were opened during the time of repair? (Due to screen cracking couldn’t properly disable private accts and etc)
Some things I see in the diagnostic/usage, during the time of repair, are “force reset” and “reset count”. Also “dup_image” and “P” “c”
Can anyone help decipher these codes and advise if possible personal files being copied.

Comment: A screen replacement would require the device to be off when replacing the screen. After turning on it would require a passcode to open. Did you have the passcode enabled? If so, it probably isn't a concern.

Comment: @christian Unfortunately, they asked to reset passcode that they can use when it was handed off to them (which is useless on my end). Can you help me understand what these codes mean? There were a lot of “p” and “c” and “binary image” these were all under the force reset history Please share your wisdom, were they trying to erase history of duplicated images? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with diagnostic and usage codes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apple does not officially provide any software or methods for this, so if you do take a step not advised from Apple, you are taking a risk that could affect your device or lose your warranty. That being said, I would just assume that you went to an Apple Authorised Service Provider. Having said that, you could speak to Apple Support or write an email to them on how individual stores and service providers handle devices and what information is required. I would only imagine that they would be allowed to take the Model number (for device identification) and your Serial number (for warranty status).